# How to share session between subdomain in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat, spring-security

I am using spring and spring security for implement multiple domain and subdomain projects.
like 
                  test.example.com/damo1 
                  test.example.com/demo2

and both are different applications with same domains. in both application i applied spring security. I want to login in demo1 application but also ask again for login for demo2 application. i want to apply Single sign On.

Cookies sharing successfully but still ask for login.
Can any help me what changes in spring security?
Please help me?
Thanx in advance

Comment: This is an application container question. In general, without some container specific setup you cannot share sessions between applications. If you want to solve it with Spring Security you can either create a custom SecurityContextRepository or use an SSO solution like CAS.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to share the sessionId between the two different application.

For this, you will need a way(pref: database) to share the sessions between the clustered nodes. As the user gets authenticated (from any of the app), save the sessionId and userdetails in the database.

When the user sends a request to the server, validate the session Id with the session Id in the database.